# get a meaningful stack trace with mocha and selenium-webdriver js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, async-await

When I can't find an element in a JavaScript selenium test, it doesn't give me an easy way to find out which line failed:

Here is an example:

```
// test.js

const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const Builder = webdriver.Builder;
const By = webdriver.By;

describe('web driver', function() {
  let driver;
  beforeEach(function() {
    return new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build().then(function(_driver) {
      driver = _driver;
    });
  });

  it('should always be able to find the element', function() {
    return driver.findElement(By.name('test-element'));
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    return driver.quit();
  });
});
```

When run like this:

```
npm install selenium-webdriver@4.0.0-alpha.1
npm install mocha@6.0.2
nvm install 8.15.1
nvm use 8.15.1
node_modules/.bin/mocha test.js
```

I get the following error:

```
     NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name="test-element"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64)
      at Object.checkLegacyResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:585:15)
      at parseHttpResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:533:13)
      at Executor.execute (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7
```

which is easy to make sense of in this test, but it is really hard in longer tests as it does not give me a line of my test, and I am often searching for the same element more than once.

Is there a way to fix this?

(my actual tests are with async/await, but I did this example without and the problem is the same)

Comment: what if you use [bluebird](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/stack-traces-for-promises-in-node-js-46bf5f490fe4) to get the proper stack trace for asynchronous code ?

Comment: I just tried it, but it doesn't solve it.  The stack trace for non selenium assertion failures is already good enough, and the stack trace for selenium is has no line numbers in my script either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I've got a better workaround.

Here is a more sophisticated fix than mine: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/pull/6355/files (mentioned on the bug report for this issue https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7626)

I just wrap every single call to a `driver` method in this wrapper: https://gitlab.com/alex028502/binary-tools/-/tree/master/ip-address/fix-selenium-stack-trace

(I think you need at least node 12 for this to work)

```
function fixSeleniumStackTrace (snippet) {
  const stack = new Error('start of stack trace wrapper').stack;
  try {
    return Promise.resolve(snippet()).catch(function(e) {
      e.stack = e.stack + '\n' + stack;
      throw e;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    e.stack = e.stack + '\n' + stack;
    throw e;
  }
};
```

like this

```
const bodyTag = await fixSeleniumStackTrace(function () {
  return driver.findElement(By.tagName('body'));
});
```

and since most of my calls are in helpers, it's not as bad as it looks.  I only need to wrap the calls in my helpers.  I can turn off the SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER in version 3, or use version 4.

Answer (score 0):

The work around that I eventually settled on is... switch to selenium-webdriver 3, and then keep the promise manager turned on.

```
$ npm install selenium-webdriver@3.6.0
```

then try with the promise manager turned off (as is the default in 4)

```
$ SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER=False node_modules/.bin/mocha test.js

  web driver
    1) should always be able to find the element


  0 passing (728ms)
  1 failing

  1) web driver
       should always be able to find the element:
     NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name="test-element"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=72.0.3626.69 (3c16f8a135abc0d4da2dff33804db79b849a7c38),platform=Linux 4.15.0-64-generic x86_64)
      at Object.checkLegacyResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
      at parseHttpResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
      at doSend.then.response (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

and then turn it back on again

```
$ SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER=True node_modules/.bin/mocha test.js


  web driver
    1) should always be able to find the element


  0 passing (752ms)
  1 failing

  1) web driver
       should always be able to find the element:
     NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name="test-element"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=72.0.3626.69 (3c16f8a135abc0d4da2dff33804db79b849a7c38),platform=Linux 4.15.0-64-generic x86_64)
      at Object.checkLegacyResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
      at parseHttpResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
      at doSend.then.response (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
  From: Task: WebDriver.findElement(By(css selector, *[name="test-element"]))
      at Driver.schedule (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
      at Driver.findElement (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1014:17)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test.js:16:19)
      at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
      at TaskQueue.execute_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
      at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
      at asyncRun (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
      at /home/alex/pex2/selenium-line-workaround/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

This wasn't the only thing messing with my stack trace.  instanbul/nyc and async/await also caused issues.  Node 12 has solved the async/await problem.  However, the available version of selenium-webdriver@4 still doesn't give the right stack trace even *with* node-12.  Since instanbul/nyc also messes up the stack trace line numbers, I have settled on running the tests twice, with node-12, as follows:

1. SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER on, with no coverage report, to get the correct line numbers
2. SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER off, with coverage check on: both to check coverage, and since the line numbers are going to be wrong anyhow, take the opportunity to make sure that my selenium tests work without the promise manager, and that I have awaits in all the right places

Once they fix `selenium-webdriver@4`, this should be easier

Answer (score 0):

Try this(works with latest selenium webdriver i.e **4.0.0-alpha.5**)

**In .babelrc file**

```
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "sourceMaps": "both"
}
```

**In package.json file**

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require @babel/polyfill --require @babel/register --timeout 10000"
  }
```

Please refer how to setup mocha with babel [link](https://babeljs.io/en/setup#installation)

```
     NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"ForgoT"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.87)
      at Object.throwDecodedError (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
      at parseHttpResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:563:13)
      at Executor.execute (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:489:26)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
      at Driver.execute (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:699:17)
      at toWireValue (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:138:15)
      at /home/deepak/myApps/junk/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:189:16
      at forEachKey (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:183:9)
      at convertKeys (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:188:3)
      at Driver.execute (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:697:22)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/sampleDriver.js:29:5)
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your answer.  I still don't see any mention of `test.js` in the stack trace even when I I do the above.  What does your fixed stack trace look like?

Comment: it still doesn't say the line in `test.js` where the issue started

Comment: nothing like `at Context.<anonymous> (test.js:16:19)`

Comment: at Context.<anonymous> (test/sampleDriver.js:29:5). My file name is sampleDriver.js

Comment: oooh - different test file.  Cool.  Mine doesn't do that but I'll keep trying. thanks a lot

Comment: share your package.json file

Comment: I don't have one.  Could you please share your test file?